# Flex delete the error icon of a validated textInput

Tags: apache-flex, validation

I have a form with a horizontal layout and with this TextInput:

```
<s:TextInput id="platformNameTI" showErrorSkin="true" 
                                         showErrorTip="true"/>
```

I have a simple validator that just checks if there is something entered (required field). My problem is as the layout is horizontal, when an error occured (required file missing), all form items are shifted because of the error icon. Is there a way to delete that annoying icon or force the component to not display it?

Comment: did you tried this <s:TextInput id="platformNameTI" showErrorSkin="true" 
                                         showErrorTip="false"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<s:TextInput id="platformNameTI" showErrorSkin="true" showErrorTip="false"/>
```

> This will disable the show of the error tip hope this will help
>
> for further help with form refer this [link](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/13/validating-flex-forms-using-the-validator-classes/), hope this is wot you are
>   looking for

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. In fact, I tried to use a formItem skin with the "indicatorDisplay" visible attribute to false when in error (component displaying the required or error icon) but my formitems are still shifted cause the error icon isn't here anymore. One solution could be to have the required icon in all states but can't manage to get this working.